# iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0 Strange Pattern Rendering Texture on Sphere from COLLADA File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, opengl-es, collada

I'm using Cheetah3D to export a COLLADA file ( .dae ) and then Erik Buck's COLLADAViewer2 ( https://github.com/erikbuck/COLLADAViewer2/tree/master/COLLADAViewer2 ) program to export a modelplist format as described in his book.

My COLLADA file is a simple Sphere which I am trying to render an earth texture onto.

In the COLLADAViewer program, my exported .dae file looks fine, here's a screenshot:

[image]

The portion of my code used to render the texture on the sphere is here:

```
// Setup texture
CGImageRef imageRef =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Earth.jpg"] CGImage];

GLKTextureInfo *textureInfoEarth = [GLKTextureLoader
                               textureWithCGImage:imageRef
                               options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                        GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft, nil]
                               error:NULL];

self.baseEffect.texture2d0.name = textureInfoEarth.name;
self.baseEffect.texture2d0.target = textureInfoEarth.target;

// Enable fragment blending with Frame Buffer contents
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Unfortunately, in XCode when I build and run my sphere looks like this on the Simulator:

[image]

I'm not sure how to explain the strange pattern on the sphere, it's like the texture is there but being repeated. Can anyone please help me figure this out? Thanks -

I uploaded the xcode project I am experimenting with to Github. It uses alot of the example code from Mr. Buck's OpenGL book.

Here's the link:
https://github.com/phishstang65/renderer

Comment: could you post the code where the sphere is loaded and where it is rendered?

Comment: Hi there - rather than post alot of code I uploaded the project in question to Github, I put the link in my post. I'd really appreciate some help - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like the texture coordinates for each triangle in the model are identical.

Looking at your code I think your vertex buffer is in the format of 40 bytes per vertex, each value is a `GLFloat` of two bytes, 3 for position, 3 for normal, 2 for texture coordinates, and 2 for a second set of texture coordinates.

I ran the app, with a breakpoint after it populates the data in the `UtilityMesh` object. Looking it a dump of the data in the debugger, there is a definite pattern that repeats every 40 bytes. The first 24 bytes for position and normals vary as expected. The last eight bytes are always 0, which I think correspond to the unused second set of texture coordinates. The problem is that the eight bytes corresponding to the primary texture coordinates cycles through three values.

```
00000000 00000000 
0000003d 0000803d 
00000000 0000803d
```

So I think your program is just fine, it's just getting bad data. Check your conversion process.